# Using flink sql how to convert a string read using json_value to timestamp_ltz

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

```
CREATE TABLE roles_created_raw_v1
(
    id VARCHAR,
    created VARCHAR
    PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
      'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
      'topic' = 'sink_topic',
      'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:29092,localhost:39092',
      'properties.group.id' = 'sink_topic_id',
      'value.format' = 'json',
      'key.format' = 'json',
      'properties.allow.auto.create.topics' = 'true',
      'value.json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601',
      'sink.parallelism' = '3'
      );
```

i am trying to insert into this table using

```
insert into roles_created_raw_v1
select
    JSON_VALUE(contentJson, '$.id') as id,
    to_timestamp(JSON_VALUE(contentJson, '$.created'), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ') as created
from some_raw_table;
```

My contentJson field has

```
"contentJson": "{\"created\":\"2023-02-04T04:12:07.925Z\"}".
```

**`created` field in the `sink_topic` and table  `roles_created_raw_v1` is `null`. How to i get this converted to `timestamp_ltz` field ?**

Instead of `to_timestamp(JSON_VALUE(contentJson, '$.created'), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ')` if used `JSON_VALUE(contentJson, '$.created' RETURNING STRING)` i get the string value back.

Answer (score 0):

```
to_timestamp(replace(replace(JSON_VALUE(contentJson, '$. created'), 'T', ' '), 'Z', ' '),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
```

This seems to work.